# Differential Equation Separable Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$1 - t x(t) = 2x(t)\log(x(t))-x(t)\log(x'(t)) $$
$$\space t \geq 0  \text { and } x(0)=1$$

I followed the steps and can not figure this out. 
Getting stuck at integration...

Final answer should be

$$x(t) = \dfrac{1}{\log(C-e^t)}, C > 1$$

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What steps did you follow? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

For the integration part:
$$e^{1/x}\dfrac {x'}{x^2}=e^t$$
$$e^{1/x}\dfrac {dx}{x^2}=e^tdt$$
Substitute $u=\dfrac 1 x \implies dx=- \dfrac {du}{u^2}$
$$-e^{u}{du}=e^tdt$$
Integrate.